# Is it possible to rename Pyspark exploded columns all at once?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to explode two different struct columns, both of which have the same underlying structure, meaning there are overlapping names. Is it possible to rename/alias the columns that are returned from `explode()` all at once, and avoid a bunch of `alias()`?

Here's what I have:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = df.withColumn("first_struct_field", f.explode("first_struct_field"))\
    .withColumn("second_struct_field", f.explode("second_struct_field"))\
    .select("id_field", "first_struct_field.*", "second_struct_field.*").show(n=5)
```

| id_field | first_struct_field | second_struct_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | {"hidden": true, "type": "Personal", "description": "High"} | {"active": false, "type": "Fruit", "description": "Yellow"} |
| Second | {"hidden": true, "type": "Business", "description": "Low"} | {"active": true, "type": "Vehicle", "description": "Purple"} |

I tried to make it obvious that in the data, the two overlapping sub-items are `type` and `description` even though they don't have the same meanings between the two columns. I would want something like this:

| id_field | first_struct_field_type | first_struct_field_description | second_struct_field_type | second_struct_field_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Personal | High | Fruit | Yellow |
| Second | Business | Low | Vehicle | Purple |

Comment: you can always use forloop appropriately structured. not a difficult task.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to rename multiple columns in version=>3.4.0 (not sure if you can upgrade or have this version).

It works with a dictionary. Keys must be existing columns in the dataframe and values the new columns name. See more in the docs: [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnsRenamed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest//api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnsRenamed.html):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

rename_dict = {
"first_struct_field": "new_name_1", 
"second_struct_field": "new_name_2"
}
df = df.withColumn("first_struct_field", f.explode("first_struct_field"))\
    .withColumn("second_struct_field", f.explode("second_struct_field"))\
    .select("id_field", "first_struct_field.*", "second_struct_field.*")\
    .withColumnsRenamed(rename_dict)\
    .show(n=5)
```

In case you are not able to upgrade your pyspark version, I would do:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

rename_dict = {
"first_struct_field": "new_name_1", 
"second_struct_field": "new_name_2"
}
df = df.withColumn("first_struct_field", f.explode("first_struct_field"))\
    .withColumn("second_struct_field", f.explode("second_struct_field"))\
    .select(["id_field"] + [col(c).alias(rename_dict[c]) for c in rename_dict.keys()])\
    .show(n=5)
```